# Как сделать тестирование .py скриптов на сервере?

Tags: python, django, веб-программирование, юнит-тесты, test-automation

Делаю сайт по изучению питона. Делаю на django. Большинство функций уже продумал, но не могу придумать как делать проверку домашнего задания к урокам. Как примерно это будет происходить: юзер на странице урока либо вводит в форму код либо выбирает файл со своего компьютера и отправляет на сервер. И вот это нужно как-то протестировать, да ещё и в django. Жду ваших идей, потому что сам вообще не представляю

Comment: Посмотри как оно сделано в codewars: отосланный код тестируется насколько я понимаю на обычном unittest. Тока тут надо что-то придумать с  security, а то буит там...

Comment: Приведите пример задания и ответа на него. Тут важно понимать, как в принципе можно протестировать код, перед тем как это реализовать безопасно на сервере. Т.е. для ответа на вопрос нужно понимать какой API у задания. Т.е. это может быть одна функция с заданными параметрами или это целый скрипт, который предполагается вызывать именно как скрипт?